Is there a flaw to represent an ability being undone when a condition is met?
To clarify further I am imagining a character who uses affliction in order to turn darkness against their enemies, shadows tying them and squeezing them and so on. However I wanted to add a flaw where shining light on the afflicted person instantly undoes the affliction as the shadows disappear. Are there any flaws that would represent such a weakness?
PS:I considered 'Limited' flaw but I feel like that doesn't quite work because what I am after is not the power not activating but its effects being instantly undone.

An alternate way to look at it is a Power Loss Complication where you get a Hero Point when people effortlessly bypass your power.
